# Arrays.deepToString and Scala Array

Tags: arrays, scala

Consider the code:

```
val arr2d = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
util.Arrays.deepToString(arr2d)
```

It fails with the following error on the second line:

> Error:(79, 30) type mismatch;
>   found   : Array[Array[Int]]
>   required: Array[Object] 
>   Note: Array[Int] <: Object, but class Array is invariant in type T. 
>   You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>       util.Arrays.deepToString(arr2d)

It has problaby something with type erasure, but I am not exactly sure what to do to make the code compile, despite the compiler trying to suggest a solution. I am even more puzzled because the analogous Java code works (i.e. something along the lines of `Arrays.deepToString(new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}})`).

What is the problem in the code and how can it fixed?

Comment: This seem to work:  `java.util.Arrays.deepToString(arr2d.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]])` The original code does not work, because in **Scala** `Arrays` are _invariant_ instead of _covariant_ _(which they are in **Java**)_. BTW, Since you only need the `String`, have you consider this alternative: `arr2d.map(_.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString("[", ", ", "]")`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It works. Can you add an answer so that I can accept? Also, your alternative looks nice, but is not as universal as `deepToString` - for example, wouldn't work with arrays nested 3 times (i.e. `Array(Array(Array(1)))`).

Comment: You may write a **Macro** that using the static type of its input, generates the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own deepToString with pattern matching and recursion:

```
def deepToString(array: Array[_]): String = array.map {
  case arr: Array[_] => deepToString(arr)
  case x => x.toString
}.mkString("[", ", ", "]")

val arr2d = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
val arr3d = Array(Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4, 5, 6)), Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4, 5, 6)))

deepToString(arr2d) // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
deepToString(arr3d) // [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

This should work for n-dimensional arrays as long as n is not big enough to cause stack overflow.